# Index length by dot delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

My query in oracle is:

```
SELECT   MON_INFRAESTRUCTURE_ID,
         MON_LAYERPOINT_ID,
         MON_CHANNEL_ID,
         TO_CHAR(CONSOLIDATION_DATE,'MMYYYY'),
         SUBSTR(MONITORED_METHOD,1,INSTR(MONITORED_METHOD,'.')+INSTR(MONITORED_METHOD,'.')),
         MONITORED_METHOD_VERSION
FROM     MON_FUNCTIONAL_1D
WHERE    CONSOLIDATION_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('102015', 'MMYYYY') AND TO_DATE ('102015', 'MMYYYY')
GROUP BY MON_INFRAESTRUCTURE_ID,
         MON_LAYERPOINT_ID,
         MON_CHANNEL_ID,
         TO_CHAR(CONSOLIDATION_DATE,'MMYYYY'),
         SUBSTR(MONITORED_METHOD,1,INSTR(MONITORED_METHOD,'.')+INSTR(MONITORED_METHOD,'.')),
         MONITORED_METHOD_VERSION;
```

And the OUTPUT is:

```
1   2   001 102015  SI.MCA  19
1   2   001 102015  SI.MCA  20
1   2   001 102015  SI.MCA  29
1   2   001 102015  SI.MCA  26
```

How to index the 5th column by dots to output SI.MCA.Random_Name. ?

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking... what are you trying to index? Where is random_name coming from?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "index the 5th column by dots"? Please edit your question to show the output you'd like to get.